# Cloudformation to terraform conversion of SSM parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am converting a Cloudformation template to terraform. following CF code:

**Cloudformation:**

```
lbdServicesBInfoParameter:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter'
    Properties:
      Type: String
      Name: !Join 
        - ''
        - - /DepConf/
          - !Ref EnvName
          - /LKDs/lbdServicesBInfo
      Value: !Ref lbdServicesBInfo
```

**Terraform**

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "lbdServicesBInfoParameter" {
  name  = "lbdServicesBInfoParameter"
  type  = "String"
  value = "/LKDs/lbdServicesBInfo"
}
```

I am not sure whether the above conversion is right. Can you please correct me iff I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our `lbdServicesBInfoParameter` CFN template, the terraform should be:

```
variable "EnvName" {
    default = some-name
}

variable "lbdServicesBInfo" {
    default = some-value
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "lbdServicesBInfoParameter" {
  name  = "/DepConf/${var.EnvName}/LKDs/lbdServicesBInfo"
  type  = "String"
  value =  var.lbdServicesBInfo
}
```

Obviously, `var.EnvName` and `var.lbdServicesBInfo` should be set with correct values.